# Losing value of hiddenfield on reusing user control on same page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am facing this strange problem with a reusable user control that I have designed. I have a text box, an AutoCompleteExtender on this control, a webservice that returns key value pair and on item selection from AutoCompleteExtender, I am invoking a javascript on the event OnClientItemSelected to store the keys (from key value pair) of the selected item in a hidden field, later on clicking button say “OK” in the backend I am regenerating the selected ListItems in key value pair fashion.

This was working fine when this usercontrol used alone on the page.

Now on the main page I am using the same usercontrol 3 times. Like

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" Tagname="Control1" Src = “~/control.ascx”%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc2" Tagname="Control2" Src = “~/control.ascx”%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc3" Tagname="Control3" Src = “~/control.ascx”%>
```

Everything works well till I try to regenerate the Key value pair, I debugged the code and noticed that java script is setting the value of the key to the hidden field however when I click on the “OK” and a post back the key stored in the hidden field is blank.

Comment: If you check the hidden field when clicking OK (with `alert` or `console.log` in `OnClientClick` event of the button), before the form is submitted, the value is still there?

Comment: Yes, it is there. I noticed as I am using the control 3 times on the page, 3 javascript blocks with different Client IDs were created. but only one was storing the value, also my bad I am using jQuery.

Comment: I was going to ask how you store the value exactly but I am not familar with jQuery. If you put another hidden field in the form and set a value in it the same way, you can retrieve it in code-behind? (Sorry if this question sounds "stupid")

Comment: By the way, in user controls that can appear several times in a form, I tend to use binding expressions like `'<%= hiddenMinDate.ClientID %>'` to get their ID in Javascript code. I don't know if that makes sense with jQuery and if it can help you.

Comment: the function looks like this: 
function ClientItemSelected(sender,e)
{$get('<%=hiddenfield.ClientID%>').value = e.get_value();}